# How to find the number of rows giving the same result two columns of a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many columns and rows. I wish to find the number of rows in two columns that both give '1' as simply as possible.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, you should probably read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The wording of your question is a bit confusing. Can you do something like `nrow(df)`?